# Circular and external references in EF 6 entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two models:

```
class Site {
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual Page RootPage { get; set; }
}

class Page {
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual string Content { get; set; }
  public virtual Site ContainingSite { get; set; }
  public virtual Page ParentPage { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Page> NestedPages { get; set; }
}
```

Pages can be nested, but they all must be bound to a site. However, any site can only have one root page.

The configuration is as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Site>().HasRequired(x => x.RootPage).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.ContainingSite);
modelBuilder.Entity<Page>().HasMany(x => x.NestedPages).WithOptional(x => x.ParentPage);
```

I keep getting this error when inserting data:

```
Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Site_RootPage_Target' of the relationship 'MySite.DataModel.Site_RootPage' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.
```

How do I configure EF to make it understand my structure?

Comment: Your `ParentPage` should be a `Page` and not a `Site` right? Also, shouldn't `RootPage` and `ContainingSite` be part of different relationships? It seems like a `Site` would only have one `RootPage`, but many `Page`s could be associated with a single `Site`. If you want to make sure `someSite.RootPage.ContainingSite == someSite`, then I think you might need to use validations.

Comment: @jjj, yes, sorry for the typo. And you're right, `Site` has one `RootPage`, but many `Page`s are bound to one site. Could you tell me more about the validations?

Comment: Validations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Multiplicity constraint violated.`

You're getting this error because you're likely trying to create multiple `Page` entities with the same `ContainingSite`, but

> `modelBuilder.Entity<Site>()
>      .HasRequired(x => x.RootPage)
>      .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.ContainingSite);`

[creates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx) a [one-to-one](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1to1/) relationship, where `someSite.RootPage.ContainingSite == someSite` and `somePage.ContainingSite.RootPage == somePage`.

---

It might make more sense to have three different relationships:

- Each `Site` has a root `Page`
- Each `Page` is part of a containing `Site` (or each `Site` has many `Page`s)
- Each `Page` has many nested `Page`s

...though maintaining consistency could be difficult if you want to make sure a `Page` and its `.ParentPage` and `.NestedPages` all have the same `ContainingSite`, and a `Site` and its `.RootPage.ContainingSite` are equal, etc.

---

As an aside, if you're trying to create some sort of tree structure in your database, maybe [this (starting from page 49)](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back) would help?

Comment: The `ContainingSite` property was intended to be a shortcut to get the site of any page without traversing the tree upwards. So EF doesn't support just storing a reference to an arbitrary entity without having a proper relationship?

Comment: If there are supposed to be many `Page`s with the same `ContainingSite`, then you can't use the relationship that you had. You would need something like `modelBuilder.Entity<Page>().HasRequired(s => s.ContainingSite).WithMany()`, and then a separate relationship with `modelBuilder.Entity<Site>().HasRequired(x => x.RootPage).WithOptional()` in addition to your third relationship. The key situation would be interesting though, as would maintaining consistency....

Comment: Well, anyway, I followed your advice and replaced the naive tree implementation with a path-based one from the presentation. Fixed the current issue and made loading subtrees a deal easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the "Site ContainingSite" line from Page, 
and just use page's ParentPage to navigate to the containing site.
e.g.   this.RootPage.ContainSite